# programmatically monitoring of outbound azure app service connection

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We have an azure app service backed up with an S3 plan hosting plenty of webjobs (dotnet/nodejs) performing outbound connections (azure service bus, external REST API, telemetry, etc).

On peak usage, we start to encounter time out issues from above services as we are exceeding the max number of outbound connections for S3 instance: 8064 (SNAT post exhaustion)

[image]

We have already plenty of pool & cache mechanisms, but it's complex to tune as spread over > 15 different webjobs.

- is there a way to have fine tracking of SNAT exhaustion per process ? (current report provide only the machine name). `TCP connections` reports only track remote addresses. 
  [image]
- is there way to retrieve this metric live programmatically (C# / nodejs) in order to try dynamic internal pool adjustement ?
- better approach ? peaks are occurring seldom in an enterprise service bus scenario, time out errors, can be then resume and fix. buying a bigger app plan instance or isolate webjobs isn't reasonable so far :)